# Seeking for a combinatorial argument for partition identities

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, enumerative-combinatorics, partitions, combinatorial-identities

Given an integer partition $\lambda$, introduce the following quantities:
\begin{align*}
c(\lambda)&=\sum_{i\geq1}\left\lceil\frac{\lambda_i}2\right\rceil, \qquad c_o(\lambda)=\sum_{i\geq1}\left\lceil\frac{\lambda_{2i-1}}2\right\rceil, \qquad
c_e(\lambda)=\sum_{i\geq1}\left\lceil\frac{\lambda_{2i}}2\right\rceil, \\
f(\lambda)&=\sum_{i\geq1}\left\lfloor\frac{\lambda_i}2\right\rfloor,  \qquad f_o(\lambda)=\sum_{i\geq1}\left\lfloor\frac{\lambda_{2i-1}}2\right\rfloor, \qquad
f_e(\lambda)=\sum_{i\geq1}\left\lfloor\frac{\lambda_{2i}}2\right\rfloor, \\
a_o(\lambda)&=\sum_{i\geq1}\lambda_{2i-1}, \qquad
a_e(\lambda)=\sum_{i\geq1}\lambda_{2i}.
\end{align*}
With these in mind, we have the following identities:

> **QUESTIONS.** All sums run through all partitions of the integer $n$. Are these true?

(1) $\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}f_o(\lambda)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}c_e(\lambda)$;

(2) $\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}a_o(\lambda)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}c(\lambda)$;

(3) $\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}a_e(\lambda)=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}f(\lambda)$;

(4) $\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}(c_o(\lambda)-f_e(\lambda))
=\sum_{\lambda\vdash n}(a_o(\lambda)-a_e(\lambda))$.

**Example.** These are $\{(5), (4,1), (3,2), (3,1,1), (2,2,1), (2,1,1,1), (1,1,1,1,1)\}$ the partitions of $n=5$. The relevant vectors for the identities in question are:

$f_o$ in $\{(2), (2), (1), (1,0), (1,0), (1,0), (0,0,0)\}$

$c_e$ in $\{(0), (1), (1), (1), (1), (1,1), (1,1)\}$

$a_o$ in $\{(5), (4), (3), (4), (3), (3), (3)\}$

$c$ in $\{(3), (3), (3), (4), (3), (4), (5)\}$

$a_e$ in $\{(0), (1), (2), (1), (2), (2), (2)\}$

$f$ in $\{(2), (2), (2), (1), (2), (1), (0)\}$

$c_o$ in $\{(3), (2), (2), (3), (2), (2), (3)\}$

$f_e$ in $\{(0), (0), (1), (0), (1), (0), (0)\}$.

**Remark.** I can provide a generating function proof of (4), maybe others too. So, I only wish to see a combinatorial justification for each assertion.

Comment: The generating functions $\sum_{\lambda\vdash n} q^{st(\lambda)}$ for these statistics fall (conjecturally) into the following four groups: $\{f_e\}, \{c_o\}, \{f_o = c_e\}, \{c = a_o, f = a_e\}$.  The generating functions of $c$ and $f$ are not equal, but reversals of each other.  Thus one probably should try to prove equidistribution, not just equality of the sums.

Comment: The bijection to show $f_o \sim c_e$, $c \sim a_o$, $f \sim a_e$ is simply conjugation.

Comment: Using the bijectionist's toolkit in sage we can obtain these (conjectural) bijections without any effort: `N=8; A = B = [la for n in range(N) for la in Partitions(n)]; bij = Bijectionist(A, B); bij.set_statistics((sum, sum), (c, ao)); ascii_art(list(bij.minimal_subdistributions_iterator()))`, where `c` and `ao` are the statistics in the question.

Comment: Also we have $(a_o - a_e)(\lambda) + |\lambda| = 2c(\lambda')$.

Comment: I'm not sure what to put into the answer.  The check that conjugation is an interwiner is trivial, just look at the Ferrers diagram.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy to check that all four identities are true when the sum is restricted to two terms indexed by a partition $\lambda$ and its conjugate $\lambda'$. (If $\lambda=\lambda'$ then the two terms are equal, so we only need one term.) From this (1)-(4) follow by grouping the terms in conjugate pairs (or just one term when $\lambda=\lambda'$).

Here is an illustrative example for the pairing of $\lambda$ and its conjugate $\lambda'$. **Just for identity (1)**.

Let $\lambda=(5,4,2)$ so that $\lambda'=(3,3,2,2,1)$. Fill in the odd-indexed rows by alternating $a$'s and $b$'s; fill in the even-indexed rows by alternating $c$'s and $d$'s (see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0308012.pdf), pages 1-2). In the present case, these look like:

$$\lambda=\begin{array} 1 a&{\mathbf{\color{blue}b}}&a&{\mathbf{\color{blue}b}}&a \\ {\mathbf{\color{red}c}}&d&{\mathbf{\color{red}c}}&d \\ a&{\mathbf{\color{blue}b}}\end{array} \qquad
\lambda'=\begin{array} 1 a&{\mathbf{\color{blue}b}}&a \\ {\mathbf{\color{red}c}}&d&{\mathbf{\color{red}c}} \\ a&{\mathbf{\color{blue}b}} \\ {\mathbf{\color{red}c}}&d \\ a \end{array}
$$
We notice that $f_o(\mu)=\#$ of ${\mathbf{\color{blue}b}}$'s while $c_e(\mu)=\#$ of ${\mathbf{\color{red}c}}$'s in the respective diagrams. Therefore,
$$f_o(\lambda)+f_o(\lambda')=3+2=2+3=c_e(\lambda)+c_e(\lambda').$$

Comment: To add more clarity, I have appended an example. Hope this is okay with you; if not, feel free to delete it.

Comment: @T.Amdeberhan: no problem.